# sonar-maven-plugin throws duplicated resource error

Tags: scala, maven, sonarqube

I am trying to build and test a scala project.  I am using scala-test instead surefire.  I kept getting this duplicated resource error but I don't know where or what resource was duplicated.  The command I used is "maven test sonar:sonar".  Here is the output,

```
INFO: SonarQube Server 3.7.4 
[INFO] [16:36:12.615] Load batch settings 
[INFO] [16:36:12.650] User cache: /Users/carolyn_cheng/.sonar/cache 
[INFO] [16:36:12.653] Install plugins 
[INFO] [16:36:13.069] Install JDBC driver 
[INFO] [16:36:13.074] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar 
[INFO] [16:36:13.873] Initializing Hibernate 
[INFO] [16:36:15.527] Load project settings 
[INFO] [16:36:15.547] Apply project exclusions 
[INFO] [16:36:15.676]
-------------  Scan Orbit 
[INFO] [16:36:15.678] Load module settings 
[INFO] [16:36:15.790] Quality profile : [name=sonar,language=scala] 
[INFO] [16:36:15.801] Excluded tests:  
[INFO] [16:36:15.802]  
**/package-info.java 
[INFO] [16:36:15.829] Configure Maven plugins 
[INFO] [16:36:15.854] Compare to previous analysis (2014-03-03) 
[INFO] [16:36:15.862] Compare over 30 days (2014-02-05, analysis of 2014-02-26 13:57:06.0) [INFO] [16:36:15.869] Compare to previous version 
[INFO] [16:36:15.929] Base dir: /Users/carolyn_cheng/WorkSpace/Orbit 
[INFO] [16:36:15.929] Working dir: /Users/carolyn_cheng/WorkSpace/Orbit/target/sonar 
[INFO] [16:36:15.929] Source dirs: /Users/carolyn_cheng/WorkSpace/Orbit/src/main/java, /Users/carolyn_cheng/WorkSpace/Orbit/src/main/scala 
[INFO] [16:36:15.929] Test dirs: /Users/carolyn_cheng/WorkSpace/Orbit/src/test/java, /Users/carolyn_cheng/WorkSpace/Orbit/src/test/scala, /Users/carolyn_cheng/WorkSpace/Orbit/src/test/java/../scala 
[INFO] [16:36:15.929] Binary dirs: /Users/carolyn_cheng/WorkSpace/Orbit/target/classes 
[INFO] [16:36:15.929] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US 
[INFO] [16:36:15.966] Sensor ScalaSourceImporterSensor... 
[ERROR] Duplicate source for resource: org.sonar.plugins.scala.language.ScalaFile@36961e51 [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 48.765s 
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 07 16:36:18 PST 2014 
[INFO] Final Memory: 61M/445M 
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.4:sonar (default-cli) on project Orbit: Duplicate source for resource: org.sonar.plugins.scala.language.ScalaFile@36961e51 -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
```

For some reasons, I always get clover-report.xml file even though I am not using clover at the moment.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to understand how to properly format code examples. Otherwise readers will ignore your question. This appears to be a sonarqube plugin issue related to scala so I have also updated the tags. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Mark,  I highlighted the lines that have code and clicked on ' " '.  Is this the correct way to format code example?

Comment: I'm afraid not. That quotes the text, whereas using the "{}" option creates a code block. At the end of the day the UI controls are a convenience, I recommend reading the following pages: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Hope this helps! Markdown is a bit clunky in the beginning but you'll soon learn to love it. I use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I am running via sonar-runner, not via Maven, because we use SBT. I added these lines to my sonar-project.properties files [as described here](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scala):

```
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=test-reports
sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/scala-[scala-version]/coverage-report/cobertura.xml
```

Note you need to put your scala version e.g. 2.10, 2.9 where it says [scala-version]. This got the analysis to start, but then for me it is still broken because we are using [String Interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html). This was not supported until Scala 2.10 and it breaks the Scala analyzer. I started to update the jars that being included in the Maven POM, but moving the plugin to Scala 2.10 is non-trivial because it uses [reflect.generic.ModifierFlags](https://github.com/butlermh/sonar-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/sonar/plugins/scala/metrics/PublicApiCounter.scala#L22)
which [was removed after 2.9.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/reflect/generic/ModifierFlags.html). This is all fixable but I will need to look at the Scala source! Maybe it will work for you if you are using Scala 2.9.

Comment: There is a branch here of the plugin that has been updated to Scala 2.10 but I haven't tried it https://github.com/RadoBuransky/sonar-scala/commits/scala